# Outlook 2007 rules on fresh Windows installation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have an user with a fresh Windows installation and he is experiencing issues with rules he used to have configured.

Basically the rules are not being applied and all the messages are being sent to his inbox. If I try to run the rules manually I get a message that says "Client only rule...". The rules are applied to messages that arrive to an Exchange mailbox and the messages are moved to folders that are on the same Exchange mailbox, so it is all on the server side. If I edit the rule there's a box checked that is title "Only for this machine".

What are some workarounds to this?

Comment: After you installed, were the rules inserted into Outlook from the Exchange server, or were they manually added?  If they were created previously in a different version of Outlook, what version was it?

Comment: The rules were automatically inserted into Outlook from Exchange. Same version.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, check out [MS KB892240 - "After you configure one or more client-only message rules in Outlook, other message rules do not take effect"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892240):

> Symptom: After you configure one or more client-only message rules in
>   Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, Microsoft Office Outlook 2003,
>   Microsoft Office Outlook 2002, or Microsoft Office Outlook 2000, other
>   message rules that you have configured in Microsoft Outlook do not
>   take effect when you receive an e-mail message.
>
> . . .
>
> This issue occurs if all the following conditions are true:
>
> - You create a client-only message rule.
> - In the client-only message rule, you click to select the stop processing more rules check box on the What do you want to do with the
>     message? page of the Rules Wizard.
> - The client-only message rule appears ahead of the server-side rules in the Rule (applied in the order shown) list on the E-mail Rules tab
>     of the Rules and Alerts dialog box in Outlook.
>
> When a rule that contains a client-only condition appears in the Rule
>   (applied in the order shown) list in Outlook, and if this rule has the
>   stop processing more rules check box selected, none of the server-side
>   message rules that appear after this client-only rule are triggered.
>   Exchange Server cannot evaluate the client-only rule condition.
>   Therefore, Exchange Server cannot determine whether to process the
>   remaining server-side rules.